# ios opencv convert hexcolor to scalar color -> only get black color

Tags: ios, opencv, colors

I am following some instruction to draw polylines into image (using opencv), but i dont know why i got only black color when convert from hex color to scalar color. Here is my code:

```
 //convert hex to rgb
        const char *cStr = [obj.backColor cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; //FF0000
        long x = strtol(cStr+1, NULL, 16);
        unsigned char r, g, b;
        b = x & 0xFF;
        g = (x >> 8) & 0xFF;
        r = (x >> 16) & 0xFF;
        cv::polylines(mat, v, true, cv::Scalar((int)(r/255.0), (int)(g/255.0), (int)(b/255.0), 255), 4);
```

I debug then got :

```
x   long    16711680
r   unsigned char   '\xff'
g   unsigned char   '\0'
b   unsigned char   '\0'
```

Can someone tell me the reason? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
cv::polylines(mat, v, true, cv::Scalar((int)(r/255.0), (int)(g/255.0), (int)(b/255.0), 255), 4);
```

It is always black, because `r` `g` and `b` are already a number from 0-255 (you did &FF before), if you divide by 255 it will be between 0 and 1 and then you cast it to int which will give you in most of the cases 0 which is black.

---

If `mat` is of type CV_8UC4 then it is ok to do:

```
cv::polylines(mat, v, true, cv::Scalar(r, g, b, 255), 4);
```

if `mat` is of type CV_32F then it is ok to use values from 0-1

```
cv::polylines(mat, v, true, cv::Scalar((r/255.0), (g/255.0), (b/255.0), 255), 4);
```

---

Since you said that you are a beginner in OpenCV, be careful with the color space. OpenCV normally uses BGR(A) in most of the functions (imshow, imwrite, etc), but here the scalar is RGBA. So make sure it is in the same color space. This is just in case it does not paint the intended red line, but a blue line.